# How to add module in OrangeHRM?

Tags: php, symfony1, orangehrm

I have been working very hard to understand the flow of OrangeHRM and I have made a module also but I need to integrate that module into orange hrm. so now here the problem comes for because I can't understand where to start in orangehrm to integrate it. I know start from index.php after that edit where to get my module withing the footer and header of the OrangeHRM.

And can anyone explain me to find the path of this line

> ./symfony/web/index.php/pim/viewEmployeeList/reset/1

Comment: Defintely symfony. :) Have edited tag.

Comment: @user1654571 did you find any solution. if yes then please post the answer of your own question. I also need something like you want. thanks

Comment: @user1654571 Have a look at this page http://wiki.orangehrm.com/ohrmwiki/index.php/Developing_Symfony_Plugins hope it helps

Comment: @user1654571 you've termed that you've made new orangeHRM module, so could you tell me from where to start building new module or any links that'll help me get started